# No set method providing array access error kotlin

Tags: java, algorithm, kotlin

I'm pretty new to Kotlin and just can't get this code to work:

```
for (resource in resourceAllocation) {
    if (resource["resource"] == taskResource) {
        resource["usage"] += taskDuration
        foundResource = true
    }
}
```

it just won't let me assign any value to resource["usage"], no matter which datatypes I use.

I also tried the following, which did not fix the issue:

```
for (resource in resourceAllocation) {
    if (resource["resource"] == taskResource) {
        val currentUsage = resource["usage"] as Int
        resource["usage"] = currentUsage + taskDuration
        foundResource = true
    }
}
```

Here's the full code:

```
fun lastFinishMetric(currentSchedulePlan: List<Map<String, Any>>): Triple<Int, Int, Double> {
    var constraintResource = 0
    val resourceAllocation = mutableListOf<Map<String, Any>>()
    var latestFinish = 0

    for (task in currentSchedulePlan) {
        val taskFinish = task["finish"] as Int
        val taskResource = task["resource"] as Int
        val taskDuration = task["duration"] as Int

        if (taskFinish > latestFinish) {
            latestFinish = taskFinish
        }

        // Finds the corresponding resource on the resource list and adds task duration to it
        var foundResource = false
        for (resource in resourceAllocation) {
            if (resource["resource"] == taskResource) {
                val currentUsage = resource["usage"] as Int
                resource["usage"] = currentUsage + taskDuration
                foundResource = true
            }
        }


        // If the resource has not been visited yet, include it on the list
        if (!foundResource) {
            resourceAllocation.add(mapOf("resource" to taskResource, "usage" to taskDuration))
        }
    }

    // Finds the constraint resource (with highest allocation)
    val constraint = resourceAllocation.maxBy { it["usage"] as Int }
    constraintResource = constraint["resource"] as Int
    val constraintUsage = constraint["usage"] as Int

    // Finds the constraint occupation rate over the scheduling horizon
    val occupationRate = constraintUsage.toDouble().div(latestFinish.toDouble())

    return Triple(latestFinish, constraintResource, occupationRate)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you're using an **immutable `Map<String, Any>`** which doesn't allow you to modify its content. You just need to use [`MutableMap`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-map/) which will allow you to change the `usage` values. Something like:

```kotlin
fun lastFinishMetric(currentSchedulePlan: List<Map<String, Any>>): Triple<Int, Int, Double> {
    var constraintResource = 0
    val resourceAllocation = mutableListOf<MutableMap<String, Any>>() // <---notice this
    // Rest of code...
        // If the resource has not been visited yet, include it on the list
        if (!foundResource) {
            resourceAllocation.add(mutableMapOf("resource" to taskResource, "usage" to taskDuration)) 
                                 // ^^^^^^^^^^ Notice this
        }
    }

    // Finds the constraint resource (with highest allocation)
    val constraint = resourceAllocation.maxBy { it["usage"] as Int }
    constraintResource = constraint.get("resource") as Int // <-- Notice this
    val constraintUsage = constraint.get("usage") as Int // <-- Notice this

    // Finds the constraint occupation rate over the scheduling horizon
    val occupationRate = constraintUsage.toDouble().div(latestFinish.toDouble())

    return Triple(latestFinish, constraintResource, occupationRate)
}
```

Comment: You're right, unfortunately this did not solve the issue tho

Comment: I changed the map type to mutableMap but it doesn't fix the error.

Comment: Not sure if I got you wrong initially, but I changed the code from resourceAllocation.add(mapOf(... to mutableMapOf, nothing else. I still get the initial error. Please excuse if I understood you wrong and feel free to elaborate.

Comment: @MbeezyP did you miss the other important change: val resourceAllocation = mutableListOf **MutableMap** ?

Comment: @k314159 omg yes I did, I'm so dumb... I spent one hour troubleshooting this stuff :'(